Can't create GitHub repository because signed commits are required
I'm using Terraform to create cookie-cutter GitHub repositories:
# Create the GitHub repository, itself
resource "github_repository" "this" {

  # The default configuration of the repository
  name            = var.name
  description     = var.description
  topics          = var.topics
  visibility      = var.visibility
  has_issues      = false
  has_discussions = false
  has_projects    = false
  has_wiki        = false
  auto_init       = true

  # Setup the merge settings for the repository
  allow_merge_commit     = true
  allow_squash_merge     = true
  allow_rebase_merge     = true
  allow_auto_merge       = false
  delete_branch_on_merge = true

  # Turn on vulnerability alerts for the repository
  web_commit_signoff_required = true
  vulnerability_alerts        = true
}

# Declare the variables that should be associated with this repository
resource "github_actions_variable" "this" {
  for_each = var.variables

  repository    = github_repository.this.name
  variable_name = each.key
  value         = each.value
}

# Declare the action permissions for this repository
resource "github_actions_repository_permissions" "this" {
  repository = github_repository.this.name

  enabled         = true
  allowed_actions = "all"
}
# Create a GitHub branch called main
resource "github_branch" "main" {
  repository = github_repository.this.name
  branch     = "main"
}

# Set the main branch to this repository's default branch
resource "github_branch_default" "default" {
  repository = github_repository.this.name
  branch     = github_branch.main.branch
}

# Setup a branch protection rule on the repo to ensure that the main branch is protected
resource "github_branch_protection" "main" {
  repository_id = github_repository.this.node_id

  # Setup the base requirements for the branch protection rule
  pattern                         = "main"
  enforce_admins                  = false
  require_signed_commits          = true
  required_linear_history         = false
  allows_deletions                = false
  allows_force_pushes             = false
  require_conversation_resolution = true

  # Ensure that status checks are required
  required_status_checks {
    strict = true
  }

  # Ensure that pull request reviews are required, but that admins can still bypass
  required_pull_request_reviews {
    restrict_dismissals             = true
    require_code_owner_reviews      = true
    require_last_push_approval      = true
    required_approving_review_count = 2
    pull_request_bypassers          = [local.admins_team]
  }

  # Ensure that pushes are restricted to admins
  restrict_pushes {
    blocks_creations = true
    push_allowances  = [local.admins_team]
  }

  # Ensure that force-pushes are restricted to admins
  force_push_bypassers = [local.admins_team]
}

The plan succeeds but the apply fails with the following error:

Error: PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/{my-org}/{repo-name}: 422 Commit signoff is enforced by the organization and cannot be disabled []

I understand what this error means as I have certainly set this setting to true at the organization-level. However, when looking at the plan, I can see that web_commit_signoff_required has been set to true. What causes this error, then, and how can I address it?

ugh, this seems to be related to a bug.

The bug you mention (integrations/terraform-provider-github issue 2077 mentions in its comments:

forking the integration terraform-provider-github,

patching resource_github_repository.go#resourceGithubRepositoryUpdate() with

// There's a bug in the GitHub 2022-11-28 version, that throws a 422 error
// whenever the `web_commit_signoff_required` is set to true, even when it 
// is already true.
if !d.HasChange("web_commit_signoff_required") && d.Get("web_commit_signoff_required").(bool) {
    // remove the field from the request
    repoReq.WebCommitSignoffRequired = nil
}




With 422 being StatusUnprocessableEntity, as in 422 Unprocessable Content (unable to process the contained instructions).
I do not see a bug report on google/go-github (the Go library for accessing the GitHub v3 API) regarding 422 StatusUnprocessableEntity, WebCommitSignoffRequired or web_commit_signoff_required though.
WebCommitSignoffRequired itself was introduced with commit 642c343 in go-github v47.1.0 back in Sept. 2022.

I read that same thread but was really hoping for a solution that didn't involve forking a repository. For now, I've turned off web-signoff at the organization level, which was also listed as a workaround.
